# Do you tap or hold the free running buttons?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

So now with the inclusion of the run up and run down buttons I am struggling to understand how they work specifically.

Do you hold R2+Cross (ps4) to climb, or just to get started? Do you have to hold Circle when descending or just press it for each drop you want?

It feels like R2+Run modifier just gets you started then you can climb without pressing any buttons. Using only Cross and Circle to ascend and descend accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you hold R2+Cross (ps4) to climb, or just to get started?

You use it to climb. But just to get started! To keep climbing you can just press <kbd>R2</kbd> **or** use the **Left Sticker** to climb up. This way to **climb jump** you press <kbd>X</kbd>.

I generally prefer to hold <kbd>R2</kbd> because it has been a habit of mine.

So you're running with <kbd>R2</kbd> to a wall. To start climbing you go <kbd>R2</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. To keep on climbing up you cab hold just <kbd>R2</kbd> or climb normally (**Left Sticker** up of course).

> Do you have to hold Circle when descending or just press it for each
>   drop you want?

If you want a continued descent you must press <kbd>R2</kbd>+**Circle**. If you want to stop the descent you just stop pressing the **Circle** and you are no longer in descent.

**[EDIT]**

**Keep in mind that the direction you're holding in the Left Sticker matters for Climbing!**

I've had situation where I was holding up on the **Left Sticker** and pressing <kbd>R2</kbd>+**Circle** and I didn't descend.

There are still some bugs to it but mainly this is how it works. Hope I Helped!

Comment: I'm not sure, I've found that after some experimentation once I am in 'climb mode' I don't need to hold any buttons. You can press X when climbing to do a 'climb jump'

Comment: Yes. I usually hold the R2 to keep on running right afterwards and to avoid any unwanted behavior sometimes. I'll edit my answer a bit.

Comment: Holding R2 whilst climbing doesn't move your character.

Comment: R2 while using the Left Sticker for directions. I do it this way on every AC

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is press the buttons to get started, but you can hold the buttons if you want to

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: He wanted to know if he had to hold R2+Cross and I told him, he also wanted to know about circle and I told him so I believe that he got an answer for what he wanted

Comment: @FireStrike289 I agree you answered his question, but I think Ben's confusion is that your answer is a little unclear. Would you mind making it a little more specific?